# linux - execute qsub get script return value

Tags: linux, qsub

I execute the command:

```
qsub ./try.sh
```

the script **try.sh** returns 1
but if I try to execute `"$?`" to get the last return code,
it will give me 0 - the `qsub` command's return code.

how can I get the script's return value?

thanks!

Comment: Where do you want this value? Inside the script before exiting?

Comment: I want the value after I execute qsub in the shell. is there any command that can access the return value of a job's running script (in this case, try.sh)?

Answer (score 0):

`qstat -f <job_ID>` contains an `exit_status` line with the script's return value.

Comment: hi, i was looking and couldn't find exit_status .
can u maybe show me an example? thanks!